# Regex to match blocks of text

Tags: regex

I have some text formatted like so.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
sed diamnonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolo
re magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eose
t accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita 
kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet.
Ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed 
diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Atero eos et a
ccusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

I need to match up to and including the partial line (first line of a different length).

In the above text the pattern would match:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
sed diamnonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolo
re magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eose
t accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita 
kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet.
```

If I knew the length of each line I could use `(.{0,30})+.{0.29}` but unfortunately I do not.

I am using GLib regexes which are basically perl regexes.

Semi unrelated: This is part of a much larger regex, it will be used for the *desc* subgroup.

`/\s?>\s?(?<cmd>.+)$\n(?:(?:^.*$\n)*^\s*$\n)?^(?<name>[A-Z][a-zA-Z']*(?: [a-z]{1,3}| [A-Z][a-z']{3,})*) ?(?:[,([{-].*)?$\n(?<desc>(?:^.+$\n)+)/m`

Comment: Please provide what you have tried along with the expected output.

Comment: If you're checking length why do you need regex ?

Comment: This is part of a much longer pattern and I would like to keep it one regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that each "complete" line is 54-55 characters wide plus a newline, and the final partial line ends in a period:

```
/(?:^.{55}\n)+^.{0,54}\.\n/
```

should get you what you need. An alternate solution might be to get everything up to the first line which ends in `.\n`:

```
/.*?\.[\n\z]/m
```

Otherwise, you will need to more clearly define what constitutes a "full" vs "partial" line; as best as I know, there's no such concept as "length of the data in a capture group" in PCRE, so you aren't going to be able to handle arbitrary line lengths.

Comment: I can't depend on the last line ending in a '.' and I don't know the length of each line. So it looks like I'll have to break up my regex.